# What is the proper way to structure data in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to understand a basic concept regarding Firebase data structure and the callbacks.

If i have a users object:

```
users
    userid
       username: "my name"
       userpic: "http://coolpic.jpg"
        ....
```

and posts object:

```
posts
   postid
       post message: "hello world"
       userid: "12345"
```

My goal is to show a listView containing posts where each post shows the username + user pic (who wrote the post) and the post message.
From what I've seen so far, if i call for post info, and then for user info (based on the userid within that post) the callback system gets the user info only after the view is populated. 
So i can't do something like :

1. get post message + userid from posts object
2. get user info from users object **based on the userid i just got from posts object**.

I noticed the "Promises" mechanic but it's only for Java Script, so the only solution i see is to store the user pic, and user name within the post object:

```
 posts  
     postid
          post message: "hello world"
          userid: "12345"
          username: "my name"
          userpic: "http://coolpic.jpg"
```

Is there another solution? it seems like a nightmare to deal with, if a user wants to change his userpic or username.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995216/join-operation-with-nosql

Comment: Well I guess you don't have much option but to make to separate callbacks for post info and user info. The Solution that you suggested at the end is not a good practice though, it will cause a bigger nightmare once you go deep in your project.